# New game and "returning player" exclusive in single player?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am hesitating to grab GTA V for PS4, now that the price is low.
While I have no interest in GTA Online, I want to remake the single player campaign.

Since I like the Railgun, and I am entitled to one since I have the PS3 version (and finished single player), I'd like to know if getting the Returning Player reward will also allow me to start the game again with the Railgun? Or it will unlock on a "copy" of my previous save?

Also, I never logged into GTA Online, is it necessary to unlock returning player reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed unlock the railgun in your single player campaign but you won't be able to start off the game with it. According to the GTAV wiki there are three ways you can unlock the railgun in your single player game.

Taken from [GTAV Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Railgun)

> - Can be bought from Ammu-Nation for $250,000 after Minor Turbulence.
> - One can be found within the wreckage of the cargo plane from Minor Turbulence, located north of Stab City.
> - Alternatively, the Railgun can be obtained if the protagonist commits suicide in the Ammu-Nation Shooting Ranges.

And also when transferring to PS4 from PS3 you will not be able to transfer your saves so you will have to start over again, but it is honestly worth it to play the entire game in first person anyway.

Comment: It is actually good news that I have to restart anyway. Is having no GTA Online account influencial in getting the exclusives?

Comment: No you do not need to log onto GTAV to get any of the returning player content.